# Django Entity Relationship Diagram models problem

Tags: python, django

so i am learning django & have a diagram to write models using it.
[here is the diagram picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovkkn.png)

but the site gives me error when i submit my answer(models).

the Bold fields are ForeinKey or PrimaryKey.
i dont have to write the dim colored fields.
and the italic ones should be inherited.

this is my code:

accounts/models.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(AbstractUser, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(AbstractUser, default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(AbstractUser, default=False)
```

and charities/models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from ..accounts.models import User


class Benefactor(models.Model):
    EXP_CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'Beginner'),
        ('1', 'average'),
        ('2', 'expert')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=EXP_CHOICES, default='0')
    free_time_per_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)


class Charity(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    reg_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)


class Task(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        ('W', 'Waiting'),
        ('A', 'Assigned'),
        ('D', 'Done'),
    )

    assigned_benefactor = models.ForeignKey(Benefactor, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    charity = models.ForeignKey(Charity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='P')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

what is the problem of my code guys? trying to solve it around 4 days and havent got anywhere. help me please. thanks.

Comment: You can directly import User model from accounts module `from accounts.models import User`. Can you share the error stack trace so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Why are you overriding is_staff etc and why are you passing AbstractUser to the BooleanFields?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Iain Shelvington.. how do i make it inherit the field from abstractuser then?

Comment: TypeError: Task() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'age_limit_to', 'gender_limit'
TypeError: User() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'phone', 'address', 'gender', 'age', 'description'

Comment: @Shadmehr you don't need to do anything to inherit fields from an abstract model, they are automatically inherited. Just use `pass` as your user model body and all fields from AbstractUser will be inherited

Comment: @Shadmehr the error suggests that the test expects *all* fields from the diagram to be implemented, maybe the dim fields should be nullable and the non-dim fields not nullable

Comment: thanks a lot. now the only issue i have is 
test_valid_benefactor. i dont know what is the problem with it. there is no error too